# PHP PDO FETCH_CLASS Inconsistent type casting

Tags: php, types, pdo, orm

I am building a PHP framework for my dissertation (Something I somewhat regret now)
This might be the last time in my life I code in PHP beyond this project, but there are some good things about it.

PHP PDO's type casting is terribly inconsistent to be as polite as possible.

What is the best workaround for this?

Here is what I have found:

- If a class property is typed as a string: If an integer is returned it converts the integer to a string (I want it to throw an exception, but this is not massively important),
- If a class property is typed as an int: If a float is returned then there is an exception because of a loss of precision (Good, but inconsistent)
- If a class property is typed as a bool: If an integer is returned any value that is greater than 0 automatically becomes true (This is a massive issue & It should throw an exception)

I am building a small ORM component for my university project.

Here is the basic example code:

```
class Animal
{
    public $id;
    public string $commonName;
    public string $scientificName;
    public float $weight;
    public ?bool $lifeSpan;
    public string $integument;
    public bool $activeAllYear;
    public string $foodType;
    public bool $territorial;
}

$connection = new map\data\sql\connection\SqlConnection('default', [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'Misc',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 3306,
    'options' => [
        'emulates' => false
    ]
]);

$connection->connect();
$weight = 10.80;
$stmt = $connection->getPdo()->prepare('SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE weight > :weight');
$stmt->bindParam('weight', $weight);
$stmt->execute();
$animals = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, Animal::class);
var_dump($animals);
```

[image: Look at lifeSpan property when set to bool it returns true]

[image: When setting lifeSpan back to int, it shows 56]

I don't expect 56 to be casted to true.

I feel the only choice I have is to get everything as PDO::FETCH_ASSOC and then manually type check everything and throw custom exceptions.
But will there be a performance overhead to this?
Is there a more native workaround?

Edit 1:

Strict types works where the class is created, but it does not work when calling fetchAll with FETCH_CLASS, It still loosely resolves and does not throw exceptions as I would expect

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Php is loosely typed, integers above 1 are truth-y. But why would you try to map an integer field in the DB onto a bool field in your class to begin with?

Comment: I wouldn't, I was just seeing the language behaviour. But thanks for the clarification, If this is how the language is, then I will just leave it at that. If I wanted to provide strict type safety, I could manually do this I guess? But will there be a performance overhead to this?

Comment: Yes it's how php is, it's not really PDO's fault. For reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Thank you, I guess its best to leave it like that, No point going against the language infrastructure. I will create another Java version where I can strict type safety

Comment: There's likely to be a small overhead to adding your own checks, yes, but you'd have to test to see if it's noticeable, or at what scale it starts to be noticeable